# can't delete key from shared preferences.string list

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

so newbie question but i think i have done everything in accordance with the documentation and i can't find the bug i have List string with shared preferences and 3 function laod save delete ,load and save work perfect but delete doing nothing without errors :/

```
     List favorites=[];
    @override 
    void initState(){
    super.initState();
    setState(() {
    _loadList();
      });}

   _loadList() async {
     SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
  favorites = (prefs.getStringList('myFavorites') ?? []);
   });
    }

  _saveList(documentID) async{
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  prefs.setStringList('myFavorites', ['$documentID']);
  _loadList();
  }

  _deleteList(documentID) async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
   var list= prefs.getStringList('myFavorites');
    list.remove(documentID);
   _loadList();}
```

I couldn't find too many questions about it, I think my own stupidity forgets something. can someone help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a new list and add all keys to new list. deleted documentId in my new list and put the new list in place of myFavorites. Also works.